# Magento2: value_index in configurable product API

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, api, configurable-product-options

In official REST API guide [Step 4. Define configurable product options](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/tutorials/configurable-product/define-config-product-options.html), there are payload like below.

```
{
  "option": {
    "attribute_id": "141",
    "label": "Size",
    "position": 0,
    "is_use_default": true,
    "values": [
      {
        "value_index": 9
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Other parameters I can understand, but what is the function of **value_index**?

The guide just said

> The value assigned to the `value_index` must be unique within the system.

I have **huge** configurable products to create by the API, how can I make sure the `value_index` **different in each creation**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Value_index" is the configurable  attribute option Id, which you want to use for this product . 
Simply it is configurable attribute's option id.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why the id not auto generate? I have to assign it every time? I have huge configurable products to create by the API, how can I make sure the `value_index` different in each creation?

Answer (score 0):

After a research, I found in **Magento 1.9**, the configurable product `value_index` is the **configurable attribute option value**, which could get by

```
$configurableAttributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
print_r($configurableAttributes);
```

In **Magento 2**, the configurable product `value_index` is the **configurable 
 attribute option value** too.

---

**But**, when use the **Magento2 API**, after my test, we could give the `value_index` some **unique integer**, like child product id, it will **work too**. We **do not** necessarily need the `configurable attribute option value` in the `value_index`.