# Create configurable product using rest api magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, rest-api, webapi

I am new to Magento 2 and learning Rest API. 
I was trying to create configurable products using Rest API but I am not getting fully success.

I am able to create a configurable product and simple products.
Later I am not able to connect/line simple products to configurable product. I followed Magento [rest API tutorial](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/tutorials/configurable-product/define-config-product-options.html) but in my opinion, it is not cleared.

I have created a configurable product whose sku is 747682908 and simple products have sku like this 747682908-colors-size and so on.

I am now adding following thing to add options

```
$option = [
    "option" => [
        "attribute_id"=> "63",
        "label"=> "Size",
        "values"=> [
            ["value_index"=> 54164121323] //random int I  dont know what the hell is it.
        ]
    ],
];
```

This is the post URL: http://localhost/magentoTest5/rest/V1/configurable-products/747682908/options

I run the this url and later when i call this url

```
postData("http://localhost/magentoTest5/rest/V1/configurable-products/747682908/child", ["childSku"=>"747682908-grey-xxs"])
```

I get the web-5b78d12fd12 error.

```
[2018-11-05 16:36:52] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5be071a475f7a; Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entity_value.value' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `entity`.`sku`, `product_entity`.`entity_id` AS `product_id`, `attribute`.`attribute_code`, `entity_value`.`value` AS `value_index`, `attribute_label`.`value` AS `super_attribute_label`, IFNULL(option_value.value, default_option_value.value) AS `option_title`, `default_option_value`.`value` AS `default_title` FROM `catalog_product_super_attribute` AS `super_attribute`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `product_entity` ON product_entity.entity_id = super_attribute.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `product_link` ON product_link.parent_id = super_attribute.product_id
 INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS `attribute` ON attribute.attribute_id = super_attribute.attribute_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `entity` ON entity.entity_id = product_link.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `entity_value` ON entity_value.attribute_id = super_attribute.attribute_id AND entity_value.store_id = 0 AND entity_value.entity_id = entity.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_attribute_label` AS `attribute_label` ON super_attribute.product_super_attribute_id = attribute_label.product_super_attribute_id AND attribute_label.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option` AS `attribute_option` ON attribute_option.option_id = entity_value.value
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `option_value` ON option_value.option_id = entity_value.value AND option_value.store_id = 1
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `default_option_value` ON default_option_value.option_id = entity_value.value AND default_option_value.store_id = 0 WHERE (super_attribute.product_id = 6) AND (attribute.attribute_id = '') ORDER BY `attribute_option`.`sort_order` ASC
 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 42): Report ID: webapi-5be071a475f7a; Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entity_value.value' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `entity`.`sku`, `product_entity`.`entity_id` AS `product_id`, `attribute`.`attribute_code`, `entity_value`.`value` AS `value_index`, `attribute_label`.`value` AS `super_attribute_label`, IFNULL(option_value.value, default_option_value.value) AS `option_title`, `default_option_value`.`value` AS `default_title` FROM `catalog_product_super_attribute` AS `super_attribute`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `product_entity` ON product_entity.entity_id = super_attribute.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `product_link` ON product_link.parent_id = super_attribute.product_id
 INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS `attribute` ON attribute.attribute_id = super_attribute.attribute_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `entity` ON entity.entity_id = product_link.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `entity_value` ON entity_value.attribute_id = super_attribute.attribute_id AND entity_value.store_id = 0 AND entity_value.entity_id = entity.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_attribute_label` AS `attribute_label` ON super_attribute.product_super_attribute_id = attribute_label.product_super_attribute_id AND attribute_label.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option` AS `attribute_option` ON attribute_option.option_id = entity_value.value
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `option_value` ON option_value.option_id = entity_value.value AND option_value.store_id = 1
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `default_option_value` ON default_option_value.option_id = entity_value.value AND default_option_value.store_id = 0 WHERE (super_attribute.product_id = 6) AND (attribute.attribute_id = '') ORDER BY `attribute_option`.`sort_order` ASC
 at /var/www/html/magentoTest5/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:205, Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entity_value.value' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `entity`.`sku`, `product_entity`.`entity_id` AS `product_id`, `attribute`.`attribute_code`, `entity_value`.`value` AS `value_index`, `attribute_label`.`value` AS `super_attribute_label`, IFNULL(option_value.value, default_option_value.value) AS `option_title`, `default_option_value`.`value` AS `default_title` FROM `catalog_product_super_attribute` AS `super_attribute`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `product_entity` ON product_entity.entity_id = super_attribute.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `product_link` ON product_link.parent_id = super_attribute.product_id
 INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS `attribute` ON attribute.attribute_id = super_attribute.attribute_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `entity` ON entity.entity_id = product_link.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `entity_value` ON entity_value.attribute_id = super_attribute.attribute_id AND entity_value.store_id = 0 AND entity_value.entity_id = entity.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_attribute_label` AS `attribute_label` ON super_attribute.product_super_attribute_id = attribute_label.product_super_attribute_id AND attribute_label.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option` AS `attribute_option` ON attribute_option.option_id = entity_value.value
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `option_value` ON option_value.option_id = entity_value.value AND option_value.store_id = 1
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `default_option_value` ON default_option_value.option_id = entity_value.value AND default_option_value.store_id = 0 WHERE (super_attribute.product_id = 6) AND (attribute.attribute_id = '') ORDER BY `attribute_option`.`sort_order` ASC
 at /var/www/html/magentoTest5/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entity_value.value' in 'field list' at /var/www/html/magentoTest5/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"
```

Please, anybody, help me to solve the issue.

In short: how do I add/link simple products to the configurable products and what is the `value_index`? I googled it also but Didn't find any solution.

Please help me.
Thanks in advanced for any help.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the variable `$option` you're creating doesn't follow the guidelines you find in the Magento DevDoc.

Payload should be

```
{
  "option": {
    "attribute_id": "141",
    "label": "Size",
    "position": 0,
    "is_use_default": true,
    "values": [ // -> this is an array
      { // -> this is an object within an array
        "value_index": 9 
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What you're creating is:

```
$option = [
    "option" => [
        "attribute_id"=> "63",
        "label"=> "Size",
        "values"=> [ // -> this is an object
            [ //-> this is an object within an object
              "value_index"=> 54164121323 
            ] 
        ]
    ],
];
```

What is the response you get from http://localhost/magentoTest5/rest/V1/configurable-products/747682908/options? 200?

EDIT:

Try this instead:

```
$option = [
    "option" => [
        "attribute_id"=> "63",
        "label"=> "Size",
        "values"=> array(
            [
              "value_index"=> 100
            ] 
        )
    ],
];
```

Comment: Thank very much for answering, the values I created in `$option` variable are only those are not optionl. I get this response body `{"message":"Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5be07a11a12c9"}`

Comment: Yes, I see that are only the ones that are not optional. But the "values" key (which you used) is supposed to be an array, not an object.

Comment: I've edited the answer with a possible solution.

Comment: ok thanks but what does mean that `value_index` ?

Comment: I tried your solution but didn't worked :(

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Try again now. Read here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209016/magento2-value-index-in-configurable-product-api for value_index

Comment: what would be `configurable attribute option Id`? how do I get that one?

Comment: It's the id you want to give to the configurable attribute option.  Just like any other id in a table

Comment: how do i know any other id in a table?